# Show that infinitely many vector norms induce the same matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Consider the vector norm $\|\vec{x}\|=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|$, for $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have shown that the matrix norm induced by this vector norm is $\|A\|=\frac{1}{n}max_j\big(\sum_{i=1}^n|A_{ij}|\big)$.

I am looking to show that infinitely many vector norms induce this same matrix norm. I am a bit stumped with this and don't know where to start. My only guess is that it may have something to do with its similarity to the column sum matrix norm.

Comment: Your expression for the matrix norm is incorrect

Comment: My bad! I have just reattempted - is it equal to the column sum norm? In which case, the $\frac{1}{n}$ could be replaced by $\frac{1}{m}$ for any integer $m$ in the vector norm, and the induced matrix norm would still be the same, correct?

Comment: That's exactly right.  $\frac 1n$ could also be replaced by any $C>0$.